# T-SQL Dateformat // Timespan

Tags: sql, t-sql

In my vb.net application I used the following code, to get the TimeSpam format `DD:hh:mm` (Days hour minutes), to display user the time from creation of an entry to now.

```
Dim a As DateTime = DatatableRow.Item("CreateDate") '(DateTime)
Dim waitTime As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - a
GridviewRow.Cells(1).Value = waitTime.ToString("d\:hh\:mm")
```

Since the my GridView is getting more and more entrys working without a `DataSource` (which I always should have used) becomes insanly slow. So I decided to calculate everything I can on the database when selecting.

Now I am using the following part of my SQL Select command, to calculate the Timespan:

```
CONVERT(varchar,('" & Now & "'-CreateDate),108)
' Example sql: 
' select CONVERT(varchar,('" & Now & "'-CreateDate),108) as TimeDif from table_XY
```

108 stands for the format. On [this](http://www.itrain.de/knowhow/sql/tsql/datum/datumconvert.asp) page i found a table, that shows me all DateTime formats I could use. It is german, but you will understand the table.

There is no (or i didn't see it?) format for `DD:hh:mm`. Is there a way to customize the format, so it fits my requirement?

---

**The Solution**

```
Select *,
(SELECT 
Convert(varchar,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CreateDate,@now)/(60*24)) 
+':'+ 
RIGHT('00' + Convert(varchar,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CreateDate,@now)%(60*24)/60),2) 
+':'+ 
RIGHT('00' + Convert(varchar,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CreateDate,@now)%(60*24)%60),2))
as TimeDif
from table_xy
```

Comment: What is the format you want?

Comment: @Kaf It's written multiple times in the question... `DD:hh:mm` (D=Days,h=hours,m=minutes)

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a datatype that represents time *spans*. Trying to do any timespan based calculation inside SQL Server means you'll be using "wrong" datatypes.

Comment: Well your format would be very confusing to the user. `13:23:56` does look like a time..

Comment: @Kaf I agree, but that's a different question. I am just trying to fit customer requirements :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>There are probably easier solutions, but this should work for you:</strike>

```
select substring(convert(varchar,('" & Now & "'-CreateDate),105),0,3)
       +':'
       +substring(convert(varchar,('" & Now & "'-CreateDate),108),0,6) 
as TimeDif from table_XY
```

So basically you just use [TSQL string functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms181984.aspx) to create the format you want.

**Edit: As this is for showing a Time difference:**

you could just calculate it by yourself something like:

```
declare @now datetime
set @now=GETDATE();

SELECT 
Convert(varchar,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CreateDate, @now)/(60*24)) --get days
+':'+
Convert(varchar,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CreateDate, @now)%(60*24)/60) --get hours
+':'+
Convert(varchar,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CreateDate, @now)%(60*24)%60) --get minutes
```

Of cause, you could further format each part (with leading zero etc.)

Comment: Tricky! One more problem to solve: As soon as there are more days than a month has, the days will start from 1, because in the used dateformat to get the days there are having a separate field for the months. I'll try to solve that as well, but i would appreciate if you stay with me. Some of my entrys are 4 years old. I was almost confused when my app displayed me that's just 24 days :-)

Comment: It's a good try, but I think this won't work. I need `days` to be the `highest unit`. Using `substring` would require me to know `how many characters` the `day-count` has.

Comment: wasn't aware you were trying to show time difference into 'DD:hh:mm', will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Almost perfect! Just need to do some formatting and switch @now with CreateDate since it's returning negative numbers. But if I `*-1` these numbers they are correct.